# Web scraping struggles of a category ending in == 0$

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I an writting a Paython script to scrap a website, and I get null output when I try to get an specific class.

The block is:

```
<div class="prdt Product"> == $0
    ::before
    <!-- /cache: pl_class_46761{nULE0} -->
    <div>
        <h3 class= Title">...</div>
        ... etc, the rest of items
```

And the .py is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseurl = 'htps://www.list_of_brands.php'

headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.the_first_page_of_a_brand.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='prdt Product')

print(productlist)
```

And what I get printed is just []

I can't find where is my error... maybe something related with == $0 ?? Because it seems that it doesn't pick the container properly.

Thank you!

Comment: We cannot [replicate your exact issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without having the actual url/s you're using... or maybe the *actual* html your code is working with - but where did you get the html block in you q? If you just copied it from the site itself on your browser, that's not necessarily what's in `r.content`. Make sure that `r.status_code == 200`, and then run `with open('x.html', 'wb') as f: f.write(r.content)` and then open and see if 'x.html' looks like the page you're trying to scrape. If not, then the issue is with requests, not BeautifulSoup

Comment: Hi @Driftr95 , thank you for your reply. The URL is https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-m-406.html. While it gets correctly the class 'prdt Product Agotado', it doesn't get the other one 'prdt Product'. BTW, I have printed the r.status_code and it is 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your parser might be the issue. When I run your code with https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-m-406.html, I also don't get anything *until* I change the parser to `html.parser` - which gives me one tag in `productlist` but there is a warning message; the warning goes away if I use `html5lib`

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
```

with the above change, it prints

```
[<div class="prdt Product"><!-- /cache: pl_class_46761{BPCwo} --><div><h3 class="Title"><a href="https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-mascarilla-icing-sweet-bar-sheet-mask-sandia-p-46761.html">A'pieu - Mascarilla Icing Sweet Bar sheet Mask - Sandía</a></h3><div class="Image"><figure><a href="https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-mascarilla-icing-sweet-bar-sheet-mask-sandia-p-46761.html"><img alt="A'pieu - Mascarilla Icing Sweet Bar sheet Mask - Sandía" border="0" class="prdct-img" height="220" src="images/productos/thumbnails/a-pieu-mascarilla-icing-sweet-bar-sheet-mask-sandia-1-46761_thumb_220x220.jpg" title="A'pieu - Mascarilla Icing Sweet Bar sheet Mask - Sandía" width="220"/></a></figure></div><div class="Description">Mascarilla anatómica de algodón con vitaminas y oligoelementos que hidratan y recuperan la piel dañada.

Con extracto de Sandía que hidrataa y cuida la piel.

 <a class="MoreLink" href="https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-mascarilla-icing-sweet-bar-sheet-mask-sandia-p-46761.html">Ver +</a></div><div class="ProductBot"><div class="Price" data-price="1.90"><strong>1,90€</strong></div><div class="Rating"><span class="Stars" data-rating="5.00"><span class="BgicoN-star On" title="5"></span><span class="BgicoN-star On" title="4"></span><span class="BgicoN-star On" title="3"></span><span class="BgicoN-star On" title="2"></span><span class="BgicoN-star On" title="1"></span><span class="Active" style="width: 100%"></span></span><span class="Num">(3)</span></div><div class="BuyCn"><!-- cache: pl_boton_46761{BPCwo} --><a class="Button Buy" data-atribute="" data-href="https://www.maquillalia.com/apieu-mascarilla-icing-sweet-bar-sheet-mask-sandia-p-46761.html" data-id="46761" data-qty="6" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="nofollow" title="Comprar A'pieu - Mascarilla Icing Sweet Bar sheet Mask - Sandía">Comprar<span style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width:100%;height: 100%;"></span></a><!-- /cache: pl_boton_46761{BPCwo} --><a class="BgicoB-Fav Button fvrt Fav" data-cid="0" data-list="" data-login="0" data-pid="46761" href="javascript:void(0);"></a><div class="taxtx"><span>IVA Incl.</span><span>Precio por 100 Gr: 9,05€</span></div></div></div></div></div>]
```

---

Btw, to find any `div` with both `prdt` and `Product` classes, but not necessarily *just* those, you can use

```py
soup.find_all('div', {'class':'prdt', 'class':'Product'})
```

or preferably

```py
soup.select('div.prdt.Product')
```

and then divs with class `prdt Product Agotado`,`Product prdt`,etc will also be included.

Comment: Awesome! You are the best :D it works perfectly, and you read my mind about including both categories. Thank you so much mate!

Comment: Hi drift, just a question again: now I'm trying to get the rating values, so the inspected element is this https://prnt.sc/k4YaALUle05z but when I write soup.find('span', class_='Stars').attrs  , I get an array {'data-rating': '4.67', 'class': ['Stars']} instead the number 4.67, that it is what I need. I have tried lot of combinations from the documentation, but I can't extract just the number... do you know how to get it??

Comment: @TroyMcLure why not just use `.get`? like `soup.find('span', class_='Stars').get('data-rating')` - it's the same as `soup.find('span', class_='Stars').attrs['data-rating']`, but with `.get` you'll get `None` instead of an error if `data-rating` isn't in the array

Comment: You are right @Driftr95 , I didn't know that! I read alternatives by using "try:" but yours is much better (actually, the right mode i think xD). Thank you again!!